# Python list comprehension with class member values

Tags: python, list, select, zip, list-comprehension

I would like to end up with a list of objects by using the member variables of two lists of such objects. So to select and combine with a condition.

Example scenario, I have class Frame, with member variable KeyFrameTime:

```
class Frame:
   def __init__(self):
      self.KeyFrameTime = 0.0
```

And now two lists with such objects

```
A = Frame()
A.KeyFrameTime = 1.0
B = Frame()
B.KeyFrameTime = 2.0
FooList = [A, B]

C = Frame()
C.KeyFrameTime = 2.0
D = Frame()
D.KeyFrameTime = 3.0
BarList = [C, D]
```

And with these lists FooList and BarList, I would like to use some condition and select the objects that fulfill those values. For example if the condition would be KeyFrameTime equality, I would get the wanted list with:

```
resultList = []
for f in FooList:
   for b in BarList:
      if(f.KeyFrameTime == b.keyFrameTime):
         resultList.append(f)
```

This gives me desired resultList, however, I am wondering if zip/map/filter or list comprehension somehow to end up with same result.

Comment: What is `def class Frame:`? You define functions with `def`, you define classes with `class`.

Comment: I agree @Barmar. Its only ```class``` to define a class not ```def class```

Comment: `self.KeyFrameTime = 0.0` should be in the class's `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product()` and a list comprehension:

```
import itertools

resultList = [f for f, b in itertools.product(FooList, BarList) if f.KeyFrameTime == b.KeyFrameTime]
```